# Extract hyperlinks from ppt

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to extract all the hyperlinks present in PowerPoint and print the text along with its corresponding URLs. Can anyone help me in providing a correct java code?

I tried to use Apache POI but is not allowing me to use `gethyperlink` method. It will always give me error on this method.
It would be really helpful if anyone can provide me the solution.

My Code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.pptx") 
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(fis);
for (XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
            for (XSLFTextParagraph paragraph : textShape) {
                for (XSLFHyperlink hyperlink : paragraph.getHyperlinks()) {
                    String linkAddress = hyperlink.getAddress();
                    String linkLabel = hyperlink.getLabel();
                    System.out.println("Label: " + linkLabel);
                    System.out.println("URL: " + linkAddress);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

I tried to use `XSLFTextRun` but still getting error on `getHyperlinks` method like it is undefined for type `XSLFTextRun`.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.pptx")
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(fis);
for (XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
            for (XSLFTextParagraph paragraph : textShape.getTextParagraphs()) {
                for (XSLFTextRun textRun : paragraph.getTextRuns()) {
                    for (XSLFHyperlink hyperlink : textRun.getHyperlinks()) {
                        String linkAddress = hyperlink.getAddress();
                        String linkLabel = textRun.getRawText();
                        System.out.println("Label: " + linkLabel);
                        System.out.println("URL: " + linkAddress);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "not allowing me to use gethyperlink method. It will always give me error on this method": What error? (full stack-trace please!) - Using what code? ([minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please!).

Comment: I Just edited my question. 
For getHyperlinks - I always used to get error like -> getHyperlinks is undefined for type XSLFTextParagraph

Comment: See [class-use of XSLFHyperlink](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/class-use/XSLFHyperlink.html). A `XSLFTextParagraph` does not have access to hyperlinks. Only `XSLFTextRun` and `XSLFSimpleShape` have. One can iterate over all `XSLFTextRun` of `XSLFTextParagraph` and then try to get `XSLFHyperlink` from `XSLFTextRun` using `XSLFTextRun.getHyperlink`.

Comment: I tried to use the same as suggested by you. But still getting error.

Comment: It is singular `XSLFTextRun.getHyperlink` and not plural getHyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks it worked actually i was including textRun.getHyperlink() in for loop but it was throwing me error so i modified my code a little bit and removed a for loop with XSLFHyperlink hyperlink = textRun.getHyperlink();